# Finding the differences

Tags: excel

I have two workbooks full of products, both with over 1000 rows. I need some way to find all of the products that are in one but not another.

One of the workbooks is my English one and the other a Spanish, I just need to find out what is in the English one that isn't in the Spanish one and vice versa.

There is the same field called part_no in both tables

Comment: is there any distinguishing field? like Name, ID that same in both?

Comment: there is part_no in both

Comment: first sort both based on part_no; 
Add whats more on one sheet to another one; when both row count is equal; sort again then write an if method that check workbook1 and workbook2 path_no field's equality row by row. (I hope you understand :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid VBA, you can use the MATCH function.  This function will return the location of the first argument in the array of the second argument.  If it is not found MATCH will return NA.

Hope this helps!